# Visual Studio 2010 Distorted Menus

Tags: windows-7

I've been working with Visual Studio for more than 3 years now and I've never had a problem like this. After Installing SP1 for Visual Studio, I executed the program  and the drop down menus are very diitorted. I can't read any of the menus it doesn't happen with any of my other programs. Does anybody have an idea of what could be causing this Issue?

PS: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: I use VS2010 on various Windows 7 setups and I never noticed any issues like that with SP1...what exactly do you mean, "distorted"?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it's either a problem with either the WPF font cache or hardware acceleration.

To clear the WPF font cache, follow these instructions:

- Ensure Visual Studio is closed.
- Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to access the Run... dialog.
- Type *Services.msc*, and then click OK.
- Right-click Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache 3.0.0.0, and then click Stop.
- Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to access the Run... dialog again.
- Copy and paste *%windir%\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local* then click OK
- Find *Fontcache3.0.0.0.dat* and delete it

If that doesn't work then I would suggest temporarily disabling hardware acceleration in Visual Studio. If you go **Tools -> Options... -> Environment -> General** there is a checkbox that controls it. If disabling it makes a difference then see if the problems return if you re-enable it. Also try toggling the *Enable rich client visual experience setting*.